# How do I debug a ruby process stuck in a db transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sidekiq, pg

I have some ruby background processing running in a quite big rails app. The background processing is performed by the sidekiq gem. From time to time I experience a really strange behaviour which spins into a death spiral.

Some relatively simple jobs that does simple `UPDATE`s on single records in the connected postgresql database somehow never succeeds. The queries they perform gets stuck in postgresql as `waiting`, idle in transaction, because a transaction for the update query apparently never sends a `COMMIT`. While postgresql is waiting for this, it seems like so is the ruby background processing who sent the query! The ruby process seems to be hanging waiting for the transaction to complete from postgresql and hence not doing any further work.

My question is now, in this deadlock situation, how can I further debug where the root cause of the issue originates from? (ruby, postgresql, OS, network, something else)

PS. If I cancel the hanging transactions in postgresql manually by sending `SELECT pg_cancel_backend(faulty_pid)` then the sidekiq/ruby process which is hanging, immediately gets a connection error and gets back to normal, continuing to pick up jobs and work like nothing happened. This seems to indicate to me, that the connection between the db and ruby is still okay and the ruby process is not really stuck. But somehow something is going wrong.

PS. I'm running ruby 2.4.0, rails 4.2, Postgresql 9.3, sidekiq 4.2 and pg 0.20.0

Comment: Can you post an example of the code which hangs in postgres?

Comment: Also,  can you post any errors you're getting?

Comment: @Niels Kristian did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely do to connections to postgres getting opened by your workers which never get closed.  If you jobs retry, this compounds the problem.  To solve this you might want to run a worker like this on a schedule to clear any unclosed connections:

```
class DbIdleCleanerWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options retry: 0

  def perform()
    sql = "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
    FROM pg_stat_activity
    WHERE query != '<IDLE>' AND query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%' AND state = 'idle'
      AND now()-pg_stat_activity.query_start > interval '1 minutes'
    ORDER BY query_start desc;"
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  end
end
```

Comment: How would connection never get closed by the worker?

Comment: workers should close db connections after completing, but if you wanted to be explicit you could add `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close` to the end of this.